# CheckProcess application close

Tags: c#, process, helper

how can I make my application not open if AnyDesk and TeamViewer are open? Example: If AnyDesk and TeamViewer are running, my application will not open, but if AnyDesk and TeamViewer are closed, it will open normally.

```
Process[] runningProcs = Process.GetProcesses("Anydesk.exe");

            foreach(Process process in runningProcs)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
```

I don't know if this is right, but that's what I was trying

Comment: have you tried your code? it works? what's the error? share the results to address the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea you have is right but you don't have to get all processes twice and you don't have to use a foreach to exit. If you use a foreach on processes with only the name "Anydesk.exe," you'll exit when even only one of the apps is running and not both. You can use LINQ's convenient features to do this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var processNames = Process
        .GetProcesses()
        .Select(p => p.ProcessName);

    if (processNames.Any(name => name is "name1" or "name2"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found forbidden process");
        Environment.Exit(exitCode: 1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("No forbidden processes found");
}
```

The downside to this code is that only one of the applications needs to be running in order for the app to exit. Instead, you can use `.Contains` to ensure both are in the enumerable like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var processNames = Process
        .GetProcesses()
        .Select(p => p.ProcessName)
        .ToArray(); // Avoid multiple enumeration
    
    if (processNames.Contains("name1") && processNames.Contains("name2"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found forbidden process");
        Environment.Exit(exitCode: 1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("No forbidden processes found");
}
```

If the convenience of LINQ is too slow for your likings, you can use regular for loops and do the same things